# Store array of 8bit Chars as a String in SQL with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays, string

This should be simple but I am having the hardest time getting it to work properly.

**I have an array of 8bit integers which are indices into a 255 color palette. I want to store them in SQL as a string, then to read them back and display the image.**

I convert them to a string in javascript like so:

```
var playerString = "";
// for all the pixels in my image
    // integerVariable is the palette index for this pixel, from 0 to 255
    var chr = String.fromCharCode( integerVariable );
    playerString += chr;
return playerString;
```

In php, I store them into a TEXT field.

I later read back from SQL the field, and try to convert them back to 8bit integers like so:

```
var pixelString = "<?php echo $pixelData; ?>";
var pixelStringLength = pixelString.length;
for( var pixelI = 0; pixelI < pixelStringLength; pixelI++ )
{
    var colorIndex = pixelString.charCodeAt(pixelI)
    // assign colorIndex to the correct pixel
}
```

The problem is that the string I get from SQL is not the same one I put in. In fact, when I look at the SQL table, the string I stored is incorrect.

the string:

```
(((!!(Ãš!!!ÃšÃš!!Ãš(Ãš!!(ÃšXXX!!!(ÃšX$$!!!(GÃšXÃ¯$$!!!(GÃšXXXGÃšXXXÃšÃšGGGGÃš$Ãš$$$ÃšÃšÃš$
```

has become:

```
������(((�����������!!(ï¿½����������!!!ï¿½ï¿½����������!!ï¿½(ï¿½����������!!(�ï¿½XXX������!!!(�ï¿½X$$���!!!(Gï¿½Xï¿½$$!!!(Gï¿½XXXGï¿½XXX����ï¿½��������ï¿½���������GGGG�ï¿½���������$����ï¿½�������$$$���ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½�������$������������
```

I have tried using htmlspecialchars on the string before placing it in SQL and htmlspecialchars_decode on the string after reading it back to no avail. The string looks the same in SQL and comes out garbles the same way.

Using htmlspecialchars on the string throws an error in PHP that the string contains invalid characters. I tried using ENT_SUBSTITUTE flag but that did not help. Either way, as far as I know the string should not have any invalid characters since all the indices are between 0 and 252 for my palette.

Anyone have any ideas? This seems like something that should be very simple to do.

Comment: Why not use a `BLOB` field?

Comment: Did you make sure both your php file encoding and the DB fields are utf-8? not to mention the html page itself?

Comment: Gil - The DB field is set to latin_swedish_ci which was the default. Should I set it to utf8-ascii? htmlspecialchars was set to utf-8. The html page charset was not set to anything.

Comment: Brad - BLOB sounds like exactly what I am looking for. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Brads BLOBs are made exactly for this purpose, but if you are tied to a language that has trouble interpreting these characters in strings, then you might want to consider encoding it as a string in a different way, for instance by saving every 8 bit integer (=byte) as two characters, representing their hexadecimal value. So special values like `0` can be saved as `'00'`, `27` can be saved as `'1B'` and `255` can be saved as `'FF'`.

Comment: @NitzanWilnai My DB fields are set to utf8_general_ci, the charset of all my html pages is set to utf-8, my php files are encoded as utf-8, as well as my js and css files. It may appear too much work but it's worth it for the long run.